# Android retrofit add header and also a HttpLoggingInterceptor

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm currently studying retrofit in android:

and this is my current code:

```
 HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);


       OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

            Request newRequest  = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Globals.BEARER_TOKEN)
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    }).build();
```

How can i add my HttpLoggingInterceptor to the client and also at the same time add my header to the client?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add both interceptors calling the method `addInterceptor` twice:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Globals.BEARER_TOKEN)
                    .build();
                return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        })
   .addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that you can add 2 interceptors. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To add an interceptor to Retrofit you include it while building OkHttpClient,

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor())
```

Then you build Retrofit using this client,

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client);

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
```

Comment: How can i add a header?

Comment: you're doing it the right way in your code, you add it in the interceptor and use the new request

Comment: but retrofit can only handle 1 client only? i'm confused to your answer, why not do it using my code?